# Browser printing problems

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, zebra-printers, printers

Excuse me, my print preview is normal, but some lines are crowded together in the printout, how should I solve this problem, and what does this have to do with it?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: So what are you expecting us to do with your screenshot? Read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the first screenshot, it seems you're printing a PDF file, which means the barcode is converted by the driver into a graphic field; this is already not optimal for printing because the conversion tends to degrade the printing quality.
If this is something you can't change, it would be good to increase the barcode size and, in case either this is not possible, try to tweak the printing darkness so the narrow lines should be printed thinner.

Comment: It was printed directly with ZDesigner GK888T, I will try your suggestion

Comment: In addition, just to check that the printer is working fine, you can design and print a barcode using zebradesigner so you can narrow down the source of the problem https://www.zebra.com/gb/en/support-downloads/printer-software/zebra-designer-3-downloads.html